# Wordpress WP_Query Sort by 2 dates - custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to build one big query that is sorted by 2 custom fields (type date).
I have a query that needs to have 2 post types `['track_trip', 'training']`. Those 2 types have ACF custom fields that stand for future dates. `['date_track', 'date_training']`. How should I combine my query to sort those types based on a custom field? Both are date type of course.

```
new WP_Query([
 'post_type' => ['tourist_trip', 'training'], 
 'post_status' => 'publish', 
 'meta_key' => 'date_tourist',  ??
 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
 'order'=> 'ASC'];
])
```

Thanks guys for tips.  I was able to solve it.

````
$args_track = [
      'post_type' => ['track_trip', 'training'],
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_query' => array(
                       'relation' => 'OR',
                      'date_track_sort' => array(
                       'key' => 'date_track',
                       'type' => 'DATE'
                      ),
                       'date_training_sort' => array(
                         'key' => 'date_training',
                         'type' => 'DATE'
                       ),
      )                     ,
      'orderby' => ['date_track_sort' => 'ASC', 'date_training_sort' => 'ASC']];
    ```
````

Comment: have you tried to use the `meta_query` parameter yet? There are a lot of parameters and examples documented at the official WP dev docs for `WP_Query` at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters including how to query meta fields and how to sort things. Your meta values will need to be in a particular format though, and if they aren't in that format you will need to contact ACF support or ask other ACF users how to fix that for your fields ( ACF/3rd party plugin support is offtopic here )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on whether you're looking for one big query that returns all the 'track_trip' and 'training' posts, sorted by the two different custom meta fields, or two separate queries. But either way, you'll need to use a custom [meta_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters). You will probably also need to [orderby `meta_value_datetime`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters). Note in the "**‘orderby’ with multiple ‘meta_key’s**" section of the WP_Query documentation you can orderby an array of values, if that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: I would like to return one big query.

Comment: @Masmiix can you update your original question with that?